# keep getting 'takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' as an error

Tags: python-3.x

I get the error 'TypeError: spec() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' error line in bold. There is only ONE argument given. I am a beginner at python and have no idea what to do. Please help.

```
import random as r
from random import randint
import time as t

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health=300
        self.dammin=30
        self.dammax=55

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.health=0
        self.dammin=0
        self.dammax=0

class Goblin(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.health=25
        self.dammin=5
        self.dammax=20
    def spec(endam):
        perc=r.randint(0,100)
        if perc>0:
            endam=9001
            msg=("The goblin uses pickpocket and puts a grenade in your pocket")
        else:
            msg=("The goblin's special fails")
        print(msg)


class Orc(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.health=50
        self.dammin=20
        self.dammax=50
    def spec(endam):
        perc=r.randint(0,100)
        if perc>0:
            endam*=2
            msg=("Orc uses double hit")
        else:
            msg=("The orc's special fails")
        print(msg)


class Beast(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.health=75
        self.dammin=30
        self.dammax=60
    def spec(endam):
        print("Beast howls at the moon, for some reason. It has no effect")


en=Enemy()
go=Goblin()
orc=Orc()
be=Beast()
pl=Player()


def start():
    items={
        "small healing potion":4,
        "large healing potion":2,
        }
    effects={"Begginers Luck":2,}
    print("Welcome traveler!")
    t.sleep(0.5)
    print("lets fight!")
    t.sleep(1.5)
    print
    counter=0
    print(""*3)
    fight(counter,pl.health,items,effects)



Enemy=[go,orc,be]
EnemyName={go:"Goblin",orc:"Orc",be:"Beast"}
actions=["attack","item","run"]

def fight(counter1,plhealth,items,effects):
    en=r.choice(Enemy)
    curEnemy=EnemyName[en]
    msg="An evil %s appeared" % (curEnemy)
    print(msg)
    enhealth=en.health
    while enhealth>0:
        print("")
        endam=randint(en.dammin,en.dammax)
        t.sleep(0.5)
        **en.spec(endam)**
        if effects["Begginers Luck"] > 0:
            endam-=10
            print("Begginers Luck. Enemies deal ten less damage.")
        msg="The enemy deals %s damage" % (endam)
        print(msg)
        plhealth-=endam
        if plhealth<=0:
            death(counter1)
        hud(plhealth,enhealth)
        action=str(input(": "))
        while action not in actions:
            msg=("I dont know what %s is") % (action)
            print(msg)
            action=str(input(": "))
        t.sleep(0.5)
        if action == "attack":
            dam=randint(pl.dammin,pl.dammax)
            msg="You deal %s damage" % (dam)
            print(msg)
            enhealth -= dam
            if enhealth<0:
                enhealth = 0
        elif action == "item":
            if all in items == 0:
                print("No items left")
            else:
                itempage(plhealth,enhealth)
                item=str(input(": "))
                while item not in items:
                    msg="%s is not an item"%(item)
                    print(msg)
                    item=str(input(": "))
                while items[item]==0:
                    msg="You have no %ss left"%(item)
                    print(msg)
                    itempage(plhealth,enhealth)
                    item=str(input(": "))
                else:
                    if item =="small healing potion":
                        heal=randint(25,50)
                        oldhealth=plhealth
                        plhealth+=heal
                        if plhealth > 300:
                            plhealth = 300
                            heal=300-oldhealth
                        msg="Potion heals you %s" % (str(heal))
                        print(msg)
                    elif item =="large healing potion":
                        heal=randint(75,150)
                        oldhealth=plhealth
                        plhealth+=heal
                        if plhealth > 300:
                            plhealth = 300
                            heal=300-oldhealth
                        msg="Potion heals you %s" % (str(heal))
                        print(msg)
                    items[item]-=1



        elif action == "run":
            print("Don't be such a wimp")
        for effect in effects:
            effects[effect]-=1

        t.sleep(0.5)
    msg="The %s is dead" % (curEnemy)
    print(msg)
    counter1+=1
    t.sleep(1)
    print("")
    fight(counter1,plhealth,items,effects)


def itempage(health,enemyhealth):
    line0="______________________________________________________"
    if enemyhealth < 10:
        line1="|   Health %s                      Enemy Health %s   |"%(health,enemyhealth)
    else:
        line1="|   Health %s                      Enemy Health %s   |" % (health,enemyhealth)
    line2="|                                                    |"
    line3="|  -small healing potion-    -large healing potion-  |"
    line4="|                                                    |"
    line5="|                                  -Return-          |"
    line6="|____________________________________________________|"
    lineList=[line0, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6]
    for line in lineList:
        print(line)

def death(counter2):
    print(""*2)
    print("You are dead")
    if counter2==1:
        print("You killed 1 monster")
    else:
        msg="You killed %s monsters" % (counter2)
        print(msg)
    t.sleep(3)
    print("\n"*5)
    start()

def hud(health,enemyhealth):
    line0=(" ______________________________")
    if enemyhealth < 10:
        line1=("| Health %s   Enemy Health %s |") % (health,enemyhealth)
    else:
        line1=("| Health %s  Enemy Health %s |") % (health,enemyhealth)
    line2=("|                             |")
    line3=("|   -Attack-         -Item-   |")
    line4=("|                             |")
    line5=("|   -Run-                     |")
    line6=("|_____________________________|")
    lineList=[line0, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6]
    for line in lineList:
        print(line)

start()
```

Comment: bold didn't seem to work, its line 94 surrounded by double *

Comment: `def spec(endam):` should be `def spec(self, endam):` in *all* classes. Python implicitly passes the instance as a first argument when calling a method of a class.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly